# How can we set the Google Map with only our Hotel Information?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

We are working on the project related to Google Map integration on our website related to Hotel Industry. I would like to know that, can we integrate our Hotel list on the Google map. without displaying other hotels on the map.

**for example**

```
http://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?src=index&error_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.en-us.html%3Fsid%3D79af128e4feda3d8c3dce29a0c4b378e%3Bdcid%3D1%3B&dcid=1&sid=79af128e4feda3d8c3dce29a0c4b378e&si=ai%2Cco%2Cci%2Cre%2Cdi&ss=Favignana%2C+Italy&checkin_monthday=29&checkin_year_month=2012-11&checkout_monthday=30&checkout_year_month=2012-11&org_nr_rooms=1&org_nr_adults=2&org_nr_children=0&group_adults=2&group_children=0&dest_type=city&dest_id=-117329&ac_pageview_id=118b20a24c910096
```

in [this URL](http://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?src=index&error_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.en-us.html%3Fsid%3D79af128e4feda3d8c3dce29a0c4b378e%3Bdcid%3D1%3B&dcid=1&sid=79af128e4feda3d8c3dce29a0c4b378e&si=ai%2Cco%2Cci%2Cre%2Cdi&ss=Favignana%2C+Italy&checkin_monthday=29&checkin_year_month=2012-11&checkout_monthday=30&checkout_year_month=2012-11&org_nr_rooms=1&org_nr_adults=2&org_nr_children=0&group_adults=2&group_children=0&dest_type=city&dest_id=-117329&ac_pageview_id=118b20a24c910096) there is a option "Show map" left side. On this map, booking.com shows the selected hotels list on the map, and other hotels are not displaying in this map.

Thanks 
Sam

Answer (score 0):

That can be done by using a [Styled Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) that doesn't display "Points of Interest" (poi).