# Is there anyway to get a blank map with only imported data?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm an amateur web developer (by amateur I mean very low beginner level). I work at a Tour Operator and we recently started implementing the Google Maps API into our pages so we can show map location of lodges, hotels etc.

Unfortunately, most are already listed through Google and anyone is able to click the "View in Google Maps" option and get direct contact details (which is what we're trying to avoid as we work on commission.)

Is there any way to get a blank map so it only displays the points we plot?

If it helps, I'm currently using the Marker with Label javascript with the API

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we set the Google Map with only our Hotel Information?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621632/how-can-we-set-the-google-map-with-only-our-hotel-information)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API Click Point Marker (not custom)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466805/google-maps-api-click-point-marker-not-custom)

Answer (score 2):

You mean is you need to Remove “labels” and all extra information from the map right.
you may go with adding some styles to your google map script.
here is full code for map withour information.
it may help.
you can change the colors and other styles if you needs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Google map test demo</title>

        <style type="text/css">
        /* Set a size for our map container, the Google Map will take up 100% of this container */
        #map {
            width: 750px;
            height: 500px;
        }
        </style>

        <!-- 
        You need to include this script tag on any page that has a Google Map.

        The following script tag will work when opening this example locally on your computer.
        But if you use this on a localhost server or a live website you will need to include an API key. 
        Sign up for one here (it's free for small usage): 
            https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

        After you sign up, use the following script tag with YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY replaced with your actual key.
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY"></script>
    -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // When the window has finished loading create our google map below
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

        function init() {
            // Basic options for a simple Google Map
            // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
            var mapOptions = {
                // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
                zoom: 11,

                // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6700, -73.9400), // New York

                // How you would like to style the map. 

                styles: [{"elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"landscape.natural","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#f5f5f2"},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi.attraction","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"poi.business","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi.medical","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi.place_of_worship","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi.school","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi.sports_complex","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","stylers":[{"color":"#71c8d4"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","stylers":[{"color":"#e5e8e7"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","stylers":[{"color":"#8ba129"}]},{"featureType":"road","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"poi.sports_complex","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#c7c7c7"},{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","stylers":[{"color":"#a0d3d3"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","stylers":[{"color":"#91b65d"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","stylers":[{"gamma":1.51}]},{"featureType":"road.local","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"poi.government","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road"},{"featureType":"road"},{},{"featureType":"road.highway"}]
            };

            // Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map 
            // We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the <body>
            var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

            // Create the Google Map using our element and options defined above
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

            // Let's also add a marker while we're at it
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6700, -73.9400),
                map: map,
                title: 'test!'
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- The element that will contain our Google Map. This is used in both the Javascript and CSS above. -->
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
```